# Woocommerce Manually Add Order: How to filter products in ajax call

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Objective: To filter or modify results fetched through woocommerce_json_search_products_and_variations

I am trying to filter products that are fetched through ajax calls on `site-url-/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=shop_order` (Manual Order addition in woocommerce)

It hits the URL `site-url/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?term=test&action=woocommerce_json_search_products_and_variations&security=xxxxx`

I am not able to find proper woocommmerce `hook/filter` to modify this.

Please suggest. I can code from there. 
[Screen where the product ajax call is made.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgkVh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the results using the below:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_json_search_found_products','filter_product_search',10,1);
```

You are passed a key/value array of the product results and the key being product ID if you need to look up the product to get additional info.